# clear a column of a TableLayoutPanel without loops?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with two columns. I want to dynamically remove all controls from the second one. Is there a **simple** way? I really don't want tedious looping and things like that.

**Edit:**
By "looping" I mean actually writing for-loops. LINQ solutions that loop behind the scenes are perfectly fine.

Comment: By "looping" I mean actually writing for-loops. LINQ solutions that loop behind the scenes are perfectly fine.

Comment: You should edit your question and put there that you dont mind LINQ solutions. By the way, a simple loop might be much faster than linq...

Comment: @GuidoG - how would you do that with one *simple* loop?

Comment: I am not saying that this particular case can be done in one loop, I am saying that writing your own loops can be much faster than using linq and that there is nothing wrong or tedious with writing loops. Just use what you prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends strongly on what you mean by: "clear a column". I chose to set the visibility to `false` for this example.

This looks really like a horrible hack:

```
// grab all controls from Colum 2 (index == 1)
List<Control> Col_2_Stuff = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Control>()
             .Where(x => tableLayoutPanel1.GetPositionFromControl(x).Column == 1).ToList();

// make them invisible
Col_2_Stuff.Select(c => { c.Visible = false; c = null; return c; }).ToList();
```

but it does the job

**EDIT:**

here is the line that actually removes them:

```
Col_2_Stuff.Select(c => { tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(c); return c; }).ToList();
```

inspired by @LarsTech: you can also call dispose and clear the list afterwards

```
Col_2_Stuff.Select(c => { tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(c); c.Dispose(); return c; }).ToList();

Col_2_Stuff.Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. By clearing, I mean removing all elements completely, like in  `
`List<T>.Clear()`.

Comment: Remove does not equal dispose.  The controls still exist.